# What is the purpose of a priority queue when heaps exist?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue, binary-heap

I know priority queues tend to use heaps but what is the point of a priority queue when they basically seem the same as heaps?  I initially thought all priority queues use hash maps to keep track of all object's locations in the heap, making finding and updating/deleting said object easier.  However, I have used Java's priority queue and you have to manually iterate over it to update or delete objects not at the root.  It seems odd to have a priority queue that appears to literally just be a heap with nothing else special about it.

Comment: A heap is just an implementation of a priority queue, [wikipedia's second paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) has a pretty nice way of putting it.

Comment: @Rogue Oops, wish I’d read that before typing up my answer. >_<

Answer (score 2):

It might help to reason by analogy here:

> `List` is to dynamic array as `PriorityQueue` is to binary heap.

That is, the abstract idea of a list (a sequence of things starting at position zero where items can be inserted and removed) is a nice, high-level concept, while a dynamic array (an array along with a capacity that doubles or 1.5x’s in size if extra space is needed) is one possible way of implementing a list. If you’re using a list, you can just think “oh, it’s a sequence, and I can put things places” without worrying how that sequence is actually represented. On the other hand, working with a dynamic array requires you to track which array elements are valid versus which ones don’t actually get used, you need to manually transfer things over when there’s no more space and think carefully about your growth strategy, etc. The distinction here is at what level you’re viewing things. If you just need “a sequence,” think “list.” If you need to build a type from scratch representing a sequence, think “dynamic array.”

This is basically what’s going on with priority queues versus binary heaps. A priority queue abstractly represents the idea of “I can put things in and they’ll come back in sorted order.” A binary heap is one specific possible way of implementing a priority queue. When working with an abstract priority queue, you can focus your thoughts purely on questions like “what elements do I want to add?” and “how do I rank them?” When working with a binary heap, you have to think about things like “do I use one-indexing or zero indexing?” and “what’s the formula for identifying the children of a node at index k?” If all you need is the ability to put things in a bag and take them out in sorted order, you can use a priority queue without worrying about how it works. If you need to build one from scratch, you can use a binary heap.

Going back to the list versus dynamic array analogy: there are many types you can use to represent lists. Dynamic arrays are one, but you could also use a circular buffer (good if you add or remove from the ends) or a linked list (good if items get moved around between lists). Similarly, there are many ways you can implement a priority queue. Binary heaps are one option, but there’s also pairing heaps, binomial heaps, etc. Keeping the relevant abstraction in focus - I just want a sequence of things, I just want a way to retrieve things in sorted order - means that you don’t need to worry as much about how things work when what you care about is what operations you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Personal opinion, you are right, Java's PriorityQueue is heap. Java as a high level programming language, it is reasonable for it to provide all the common and standard algorithm implementations, most of the time we focus on business logic development and how to get the job done faster. So we don't want spend too much time on building a priority queue from the ground up, besides it is tedious and error-prone to do it yourself.
If you want update or delete objects at the same time, and don't want to iterate over it manually, you can just do this:

```
Object updatedObject;
priorityQueue.add(priorityQueue.remove(updatedObject));
```

although it's not efficient enough when updating occurs frequently, there is an alternative algorithm called [Fibonacci heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) to do the job better:

Comment: Fibonacci heap is theoretically faster than binary heap, but in practice it's slower. The Wikipedia article you referenced, under "Practical Considerations," says, "Fibonacci heaps have a reputation for being slow in practice[18] due to large memory consumption per node and high constant factors on all operations. Recent experimental results suggest that Fibonacci heaps are more efficient in practice than most of its later derivatives, including quake heaps, violation heaps, strict Fibonacci heaps, rank pairing heaps, but less efficient than either pairing heaps or array-based heaps."

Answer (score 0):

> It seems odd to have a priority queue that appears to literally just be a heap with nothing else special about it.

Why?

Nothing about the name `PriorityQueue` promises anything more than the ability to put items in one end and get them out the other in sorted-by-priority order.  That's also basically the definition of a heap, which is why a heap makes an ideal data structure to implement a priority queue.

So, essentially, the Java Collections Framework designers implemented a heap.  Only instead of calling it a `Heap`, they called it a `PriorityQueue`.  End of story.  As the song lyric goes: "Who could ask for anything more?"

Answer (score -1):

Java's Priority queue is can be either a min Heap or a max Heap, and based on how you have constructed it, it will always give you the min/max value.